# Как передать значения дивов из одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть 2 страницы:

- Cart
- Shipping

На первой странице есть общая сумма заказа заключенная в див. Эту сумму нужно передать на вторую страницу так же заключенную в див после нажатия на кнопку.
Я не очень силен в JS, есть код но он не работает.

```html
// страница Cart.
<div class="totals-value" id="cart-total">3780.00</div>
// страница Shipping
<div class='ttl' id="totl"> $3780 .00</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('cart.html', function(data) {
      $('#totl').html($('#cart-total', data).html())
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Михаил, а можно кодом?
Я хотел через sessionStorage, но чего то не пойму как его использовать у меня в коде.

Comment: Вы можете использовать `localStorage` - локальное хранилище браузера https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage . Но, это лучше делать на `php`, к примеру, так как значение в браузере можно поменять. Можно это менять на `php` на строне сервера, к примеру: вы выводите на `php` это значение из массива, а при клике по ссылке вы передаёте `GET` - параметр, на нужной странице вы будете иметь доступ к `GET` параметру, выведете значение из массива. Если использовать локальное хранилище, то любой человек знающий локальное хранилище может поменять это значение и у сайта могут быть проблемы

Comment: @AlessandaBeretta можете написать мне вк, в моём профиле есть ссылка, могут вам там ответить на вопросы

Comment: Мне нужно именно на JavaScript и sessionStorage. У меня нет ВК. Хотелось бы получить ответ здесь

Comment: Но если Вы напишите пример, как можно это сделать на PHP, буду благодарен.

Comment: Серверную часть можно и на JS оформить. Только придётся ставить Node.js и всякое такое. С PHP тоже повозится придётся.

Comment: А какой самый простой выход из положения?
Просто перенести данные из дива одной страницы в див другой страницы.

Comment: Или вот, безсерверный вариант: одна страница просто пишет значение в куку, а другая пробует прочитать его оттуда. https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: как это сделать:?

Comment: Нужно почитать документацию, а потом взять и сделать;P

Comment: Вариантов у Вас уже достаточно. Если данных не много и хранить их нужно не долго, то воспользуйтесь Cookie прямо в браузере. Если нужно запоминать что-то на длительный период и как-то этим всем управлять, то тогда без сервера с базой данных никак. Думаю и так понятно, что Cookie Вам будет и проще, и достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Может пригодится без sessionStorage:

Содержимое страницы 1.html:

```html
<div id=mydiv>155.43</div>
<button onclick="location.href='2.html?' + document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML"> передать сумму на 2.html </button>
```

Содержимое страницы 2.html:

```html
<div id=mydiv> тут появится </div>
<script>
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = location.search.substring(1);
</script>
```

На первой странице жмём на кнопку. Более подробно читаем тут: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get/)